# Data requested from Strapi API from Next js Frontend not showing data

Tags: next.js, strapi

Hello I was trying to make a TikTok clone so I ran into an issue were by I can not display data from my strapi backend on my nextjs frontend and to inform you I allowed public request to the API code down below

```
import axios from "axios";

const Post = ({ posts, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    return <div>An error occured: {error.message}</div>;
  }
  return (
    <ul>
      {posts.length > 0 &&
        posts.map((post) => <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>)}
    </ul>
  );
};

Post.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:1337/api/posts");
    const posts = res.data;
    return { posts };
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
};

export default Post;
```

Comment: What does the axios request return? Do you get any error?

Comment: I get an error in next if I didn’t add this line   {posts.length > 0

Comment: But what does the axios request return inside `Post.getInitialProps`? Either the request is failing and returning an error, or the API isn't returning the expected response.

Comment: The API is returning data I checked through the React dev tools extension and I could see the data, just that next isn't showing data

Comment: Is `Post` a page component? Is its file under the `pages` folder? Next.js data fetching methods (`getInitialProps`/`getSeverSideProps`/`getStaticProps`) only work on page components.

Comment: Post is a page component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the corrected code after trouble shooting

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
const Post = ({ posts, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    return <div>An error occured: {error.message}</div>;
  }
  return (
       <ul>
      {posts.length > 0 &&
        posts?.map((post) => <li key={post.id}>{post.attributes.title}</li>)}
    </ul>
  );
};

Post.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:1337/api/posts");
    const posts = res.data.data;
    return { posts };
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
};

export default Post;
```